# Changing the direction of the homomorphism in the definition of pushouts

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

In the diagram below $P$ is a pushout of the data if a unique $u:P\rightarrow Q$ exists for every solution $(Q,j_1,j_2)$ (by the definition of bushouts).

My question is : Suppose that the definition was: $P$ is a pushout of the data  $(Z,X,Y)$ if there exists a unique $u:Q\rightarrow P$ s.t $uj_1=i_1$ and $uj_2=i_2$. Then why it is not true or at least not  interesting definition?

[image]

Comment: Simple answer: because $u$ satisfies $ui_1=j_1$ and $ui_2=j_2$.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? why in the definition of pushout the arrow $u$ goes in the direction $P\to Q$?

Comment: I will edit the question .. thanks

Comment: you can think like this: if there is another object $Q$ with two arrows s.t. the 'new' square commutes then you must have the arrow from $P$ to $Q$. in few words: there is only one 'vertex' for the square.

Answer (score 2):

**Added.**

*On universal properties in general.*

To say that a certain collection of data $U$ (objects and arrows in $\mathcal C$, say) is universal with respect to a property $\mathcal P$ means that whenever another collection of data $V$ (of the same nature as $U$) has $\mathcal P$, it must factor uniquely through $U$.

**NB**: The fashion in which this happens, and which makes precise the sentence "$V$ factors through $U$", depends on $\mathcal P$.

**Example** (to clarify this dependence): the kernel. Let $f:A\to B$ be a morphism in $\mathcal C$. Now look at objects $X\in\textrm{Ob}\,\mathcal C$ satisfying the property $\mathcal P$: having a morphism $i:X\to A$ such that $f\circ i=0$.
The kernel of $f$ (when it exists) is by definition the universal couple $(K,j)$ with respect to $\mathcal P$. This means:

> if another couple $(X,i)$ has $\mathcal P$, then there is a unique
>   morphism $u:X\to K$ such that $i=j\circ u$.

Moral: what really matters is that we require a factorization of $i$ through $j$, not conversely! (and, by chance, now the morphism $u$ goes in the direction of $K$: but this is because of $\mathcal P$! it is $\mathcal P$ that asks for this to happen.)

---

The pushout of the diagram $$X\overset{f}{\longleftarrow}Z\overset{g}{\longrightarrow}Y$$ is the triple $(P;i_1,i_2)$ **universal** with respect to making the square you've drawn commutative. "Universal" means that if an extraneous object $(Q;j_1,j_2)$ attempts to imitate $(P;i_1,i_2)$, then it must factor (uniquely) through the universal object: in this context, it means that $j_1,j_2$ are obtained by "passing through" the universal object, i.e. by means of a (unique) map $u:P\to Q$. This is the only possible direction because otherwise it would be the universal object which factors through a non universal one.

So, the answer is: by definition of *universal property*.

[As an aside: this is the kind of argument that one uses to show that if two objects satisfy the same universal property, then they are isomorphic via a unique isomorphism.]

---

**Also added.**

The modified definition does not give anything new (i.e. different from the original square $i_2g=i_1f$). So to give that definition is the same as to give that commutative square. (Therefore the modified definition does not define a universal construction.)

Let us use the definition as in the question: we factor the universal arrows $i_1,i_2$ through "external" ones.
So let us take a triple $(Q;j_1,j_2)$ such that $j_1f=j_2g$. Then we find a unique $u:Q\to P$ such that $i_1=uj_1$ and $i_2=uj_2$. But notice that by considering $(Q;j_1,j_2)$ we gained nothing: the new commutative square, plus the "universal property" do not say anything new:

$$i_1f=(uj_1)f=u(j_1f)=u(j_2g)=(uj_2)g=i_2g,$$

which was the content of the original square.

Comment: my teacher told me to consider the trivial group and you will see the problem. But I never sew it.

Comment: You're just repeating the definition of pushout not  explaining why the arrow goes in that direction. It's not clear what you mean by "an object X factoring through another object U". Here you seem to use it to mean that there is a unique morphism U->X (in your case, in the category of (P;i,j) that make the square commute). That is saying that U is an initial object. Of course, some universal properties actually are about final objects instead: for example, the definition of pullback uses the opposite direction.

Comment: I just repeat the definition of universal property (and to be clear, that of pushout, too) because this is the issue. And the ambiguity comes from the fact that I called "object" a triple $(Q;j_1,j_2)$. But universal properties always involve (actual) objects and arrows. The definition of pullback has *all* arrows reversed, indeed it is just a pushout in $\mathcal C^{op}$. Even there, the arrow goes in the right direction: the direction in which a non-universal arrow factors through the universal one.

Comment: Are you claiming that "universal" always means "initial" and never "final"? OK, fine, that's contrary to standard practice, but given the ability to take opposites it is no loss of generality. But you're still avoiding the OP's question: "why do we care about pushouts, which are universal things in the category of triples (Q;j1,j2) and not about universal things in the opposite of that category"?

Comment: I'm sorry to keep commenting but I don't understand what you're trying to say. Are you saying that given some kind of data you can decide by looking at its shape what "factoring through" means for a universal such datum? How does that work? If the datum is just an object X with nothing else, does your definition of universal produce an initial object or a final one? What if the data is a triple (X,f,g) where f:X->A and g:B->X? Which direction is "factoring through" in that case X->X' or X'->X?

Comment: Even if you want to restrict to the case when the data is either a cocone on a diagram or a cone on a diagram and say that you define "factoring through" for each of those two cases, you're still not answering the OP's question: why do you chose the direction of factoring through as you do in each case?

Comment: And about the stuff at the end: I also don't understand what you mean by "getting something new". Could you explain, for example, what the "something new" is for the (usual) definition of pushout?

Comment: Yes, I say that I can "decide" what factoring means. I just checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property which seems to agree with me. My answer is: "the modified definition does not define a universal construction". In the definition of pushout, the commutativity of the external triangles is a condition which is *different* from the commutativity of the initial square, while in the modified definition they are equivalent.

Comment: If you think you can "decide", could you tell me whether a "universal object" (the case of the data having no morphisms in it) is an initial object or a final object and why you think it's OK that you've decided between these two? Could you also decide on the case of mixed directions I mention above? I don't reply believe in your powers of "decision", sorry. :P

Comment: It is clear that my way of writing will never convince you, and I am very sorry for that: I am the first one thinking that it is my fault. But luckily the link I gave you explains it very well. I can try one more time: what matters is just the property in question; the property "decides" whether the universal object if final or initial. That's why Wikipedia treats the two cases (look at the two different diagrams): the important point is that anything which is *not* universal factors through the universal data, and not conversely. Those diagrams are enlightening.

Comment: As for the case of data with no morphisms, there is no hope to construct anything universal: universal with respect to what property? If you want your objects to act someway, you need arrows. Or, do you have an example of a universal construction where no arrow is involved?

Comment: There are two examples of universal construction with no arrows involved: initial object of a category and final object of category. Both deserve to be called "universal objects" in the category, if you ask me. It's funny we both think Wikipedia agrees with us: I like the part where it says "the term universal morphism refers either to an initial morphism or a terminal morphism, and the term universal property refers either to an initial property or a terminal property". It should also say, that "universal" is therefore ambigous and people should always say either initial or terminal.

Comment: (It comes close to saying that, it says: "this article uses the unambiguous terminology of initial and terminal objects".)

Answer (score 1):

The modified definition you propose makes sense, it's just not a very interesting concept. Say you had a category with a final object, that is, an object $Z$ such that for any other object $X$, there is a unique morphism $X \to Z$. Then, with the modified definition you propose, every single pushout would just be $Z$.

**Added**: in a comment on atricolf's answer you mentioned your teacher told you to think of the case of the trivial group to see the problem. That's exactly what I was getting at above: in the category of groups, the "flipped" definition of pushout would make all pushouts equal to the the trivial group, which is not very useful.